# Prometheus Alert.rules; How to filter by multiple jobs?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have an Alert configured like so:

```
ALERT ServiceDown
IF up{job!="ABC"} == 0
FOR 2m...
```

What I would like to do, is to add another job to filter out, like "XYZ", so something like this (which is not grammatically correct):

```
ALERT ServiceDown
IF up{job!="ABC" AND job!="XYZ"} == 0
FOR 2m...
```

It should be straightforward but I couldn't find any examples on `prometheus.io` or anywhere else.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the regular expression matching, in your case you want to find all time series that do NOT match job==ABC and job==XYZ. 
The `!~` label matching operator which will select labels that do not regex-match the provided string:

```
ALERT ServiceDown
IF up{job!~"ABC|XYZ"} == 0
FOR 2m...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but in trying that, I am presented with this error:`error parsing alert.rules: parse error at line 97, char 8: unexpected <op:!~> in label matching, expected identifier`

Comment: my bad, forgot `job` as part of the query., fixed it. It should read `up{job!~"ABC|XYZ"}`